# multiple gits under same directory

Tags: git, version-control, archive

How do I have 2 git repo's under the same directory structure?

Basically, I have 1 git repo for generic source code and I want a 2nd git repo to archive client specific information; being config settings, images, uploads, ...

I have clients under this directory structure.

```
           client
git-1       /src
git-2       /src/custom
git-1       /public/index.php
git-2       /public/assets
git-2       /public/uploads
git-2       /config
```

git-1 will store the source code for these paths

```
client/src 
client/public/index.php
```

git-2 - I want to archive client specific information

```
client/src/custom
client/config
client/public/assets
client/public/uploads
```

Comment: Could you give us some background on why you choose to have a single project split in two repos ?

Comment: I have the primary software in repo-1 and I want custom and config settings in repo-2.  Config settings are custom to each client and some clients have custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, there isn't anything stopping you from doing what you want to do.
You'll just have to manage 2 git repositories for a single project which can cause an unstable work flow and if/when you want to rollback to a previous commit/release, you'll have to figure out when that commit was made and line up your commits correctly to make sure you client specific information will be compatible with your source code.

**However**, Git isn't designed to be used like this. A general, stable and recommended Git setup is 1 repository for 1 project (and any dependencies managed by a dependency manager).

*Note*: You may be able to manage them as 2 separate Git repositories under 1 main Git repository using [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules); Though this is often used for large projects that use other projects as submodules.

---

Reading through the comments to your Questions, why don't you create a Git repo containing all your source code etc. with dummy client-information?

Then when you want to use your source code for a new client, just fork your Git repo and replace the dummy data for client data.
If you make a change to your source code, you can rebase/sync your forked repo(s) with your original Git repo.